# Filling a shape with a white colour and filling the rest of the image black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, creative-cloud

In Adobe Photoshop CC, say that we have filled some shape with white, how can we fill the rest of the image with black? In other words, how can we make a binary image?

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Shortkey <kbd>D</kbd> makes your foreground pure white and background color pure black. Shortkey <kbd>X</kbd> switch them.

So, just select necessary layer or shape of your project and press shortkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. It will fill it with foreground color.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Can you just kindly clarify a bit. It didn't work with me the steps you mentioned

Comment: Probably will be easier for you to use Paint Bucket Tool. You can find it at the tools bar in the group with Gradient (click and hold over gradient icon and you will see). You can fill any layer with this tool.